# Should I dispose SPWeb objects created using SPWebPipeBind?

Tags: powershell

I often write PowerShell script that rely on `SPWebPipeBind` object:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebPipeBind]$Web 
)


$actualWeb = $Web.Read()

# Do something with the $actualWeb objet

Write-Host -Foreground Green "Running script on  '$($actualWeb.Title)' ($($actualWeb.Url))"

$actualWeb.Dipose()
```

Should I dispose the actualWeb in this case?

Answer (score 3):

yes you do! its creating a new instance of the spweb object that your passing through!

> Initializes a new instance of the SPWebPipeBind class with an instance
>   of the SPWeb object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.powershell.spwebpipebind.spwebpipebind.aspx

just to clarify, i agree that it does need to be disposed as your creating a new instance, your only reading from the spweb object! as an example:

```
$actualWeb = $Web.Read()
```

the above you would dispose of:

```
$actualWeb.Dispose()
```

and you do not dispose of `$Web` object!

plenty of examples here:

[ebook](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rTBgroiWAesC&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebPipeBind&source=bl&ots=mH7EcYSuZD&sig=b1wMLRCY0x1ZrxtBDT6mz0OtPHU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QjWKUtOpHZOshQfC9IHQCg&ved=0CIoBEOgBMAk#v=onepage&q=Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebPipeBind&f=false)

Comment: No, it's not instantiating a new SPWeb if you pass one in.  Only a new SPWebPipeBind with the existing SPWeb...

Comment: just ammended my answer to make it more clear on what i mean ;) as the op is correct in what he is already disposing of!

Answer (score 1):

No, if you are passing in an SPWeb, you should dispose of it outside of your method.  If you were instantiating it within the method, then you should.  Same goes in C# programming.

Comment: My parameter is not of type `SPWeb` but `SPWebPipeBind`. That means that the caller can pass either a `SPWeb` object or a `string`. If you look at my code, I don't dispose the incoming parameter, but the result of the `read` method

Comment: Moreover, diving with Ilspy in the code, I can see that there are both calls to `OpenWeb` method and direct return of an existing SPweb object

Comment: Unless you can specifically identify if your pipe bind opened the SPWeb or received one, you shouldn't dispose it.  If it received an SPWeb and you dispose it, the object passed in would be disposed and would no longer be usable outside the method.  You could return the SPWeb from your method so it could be disposed outside.